# Python - Understanding __repr__

Tags: python, refactoring

I've defined a main function in my class as well as a method to return the properties of the object using the method `def __str__(self):`. Being that I'm calling `__repr__` inside of the class, is this the proper way of invoking this function? Also, is there a better alternative to having to use a long chain of if, elif, and else's?

**Code:**

```
def main(self):
    """Create usability of the account. Accessing the account
    should enable the user to check the account balance, make
    a deposit, and make a withdrawal."""
    main_menu = {1: 'Balance', 2: 'Deposit', 3: 'Withdraw', 4: 'Exit'}
    using_account = True

    while using_account:
        print '\nAvailable Choices:'
        print '\n'.join('%d.) %s' % (i, choice) for i, choice in
                        main_menu.iteritems())
        my_choice = int(raw_input('Enter a choice: '))
        if my_choice == 1:
            self.current_balance()
        elif my_choice == 2:
            self.deposit_funds()
        elif my_choice == 3:
            self.withdraw_funds()
        elif my_choice == 4:
            print self.__repr__()
            using_account = False
        else:
            print 'Invalid choice, try again!'
```

Comment: Use `repr(self)` instead.

Comment: @Blender this was killing me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_object.__repr__()` is called when `repr(some_object)` is invoked (whether explicitly or implicitly).  Calling it directly is fine, but most people would write `repr(self)` instead.

As to the chain of `if` statements, it's not messy enough *yet* to worry much about ;-)  One alternative:

```
int2meth = {1: "current_balance", 2: "deposit_funds",
            3: "withdraw_funds", 4: "__repr__"}
```

You can store that dict anywhere (module level, class level, ...).

Then

```
methname = int2meth.get(my_choice)
if methname is None:
    print 'Invalid choice, try again!'
else:
    getattr(self, methname)()
```

Of course a similar thing could be done with a list instead of a dict.  A dict gives another possibility:  using strings for keys instead of meaningless little integers.

Comment: Haha, thanks! I try to refactor as early as possible before things do get messy. Glad to know it wasn't as bas as I thought. I like this approach a lot.

Comment: It's a common approach, but has its own quirks.  Most importantly here, the function assigned to integer 4 doesn't do `using_account = False` - you still need another way to worm around that.  Anyway, if you're happy enough, please mark the question as finished [by marking the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

...
elif my_choice == 4:
     print self.__repr__()
...

What would happen if you did:
    print(self)

Answer (score 0):

Like all `__magic__` methods  `__repr__` is supposed to be called via an operator or an operator-like builtin function - in this case either `repr()` or the `℅r` format specifier.